# R Specify Colors From Factor

Tags: r, plot

Can anyone explain why the `col=` parameter behaves differently for plot vs text, and how I could make text behave as plot?

Here's a working example:

```
# Load Orange data from MASS library
library(MASS)
data(Orange)
# Plot data with colors
plot(Orange$circumference, col=Orange$Tree)
# (Works) Add labels without color
text(Orange$circumference, labels=Orange$Tree)
# (Fails) Add labels with color
text(Orange$circumference, labels=Orange$Tree, col=Orange$Tree)
```

Comment: Thanks @Jilber, I thought I was going crazy for a minute.

Comment: It seems to fail with factors, since as.numeric() or as.character() around Orange$Tree work.

Comment: There were some changes to the way colors were handled starting in R 3.0. I wonder if this worked in R 2.15. If so, it might be worth filing a bug report. I can't think of a good reason this should't be allowed. Although for factors, it may not be clear if you want to use the character or numeric value. If you levels are names of colors, this could get confusing.

Comment: Jilber - Thanks :-) 
@MattBagg - Ok, I just used as.numeric. Works for me. Would you put this as an answer I can accept? 
MrFlick - Agree, but in my case this isn't a problem